# How to union words/find the maximum words in one list or string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string like,

```
str1 = "dogwood;dog;cat;cattree;"
```

I want to get the union results of this string,like

```
res = "dogwood;cattree"
```

how to solve this problem? If string is not convenient, what about

```
l1 = ["dogwood","dog","cat","cattree"]
```

P.S the order of list or string is not matter, I only want the maximum words in them.

Comment: Is it a maximum matching problem?

Comment: When you convert a string to a set, you get a set of the characters.

Comment: Is it always pairs like that, a word followed by a second word that has the first as prefix?

Comment: Does order matter? What output should `str1 = "dogwood;dog;cat;cattree;"`? produce?

Comment: For that matter, what about `"cattree;tree"` or `"ball;dogballpark"`?

Comment: @Mark thank you again, order doesnt matter, only need the maxmimum words

Comment: @Grismar thanks again, in this situation, all return "cattree" and "dogballpark"

Comment: "res = set(res).union(item)" `.union` expects a sequence of elements; since you pass a string, it is iterated over. You wanted to treat the string as a single element; therefore it must be wrapped in some other sequence, e.g. `.union([item])`.

Comment: "I want to get the union results of this string" Why *shouldn't* `dog` and `cat` appear in the results? Are they not distinct from `dogwood` and `cattree`?

Comment: What if the input includes `dogwood` and `woodcat`? Should those be included separately in the results? Merged into `dogwoodcat`? Something else?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel like I said, it is a very simple example, in practice, I only want the maximum words and avoid this "sub-words"

Comment: Yes, but I can't understand what that actually means, in these specific cases.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel if input: ["dogwood","wooddog"], return ["dogwood","wooddog"], if input:["wooddog", "dogwood","dog"] or ["wooddog", "dogwood","wood"] ,return ["dogwood","wooddog"],  just provide any idea or algo, it's necessary for me to solve actual problems

Comment: So the rule is, to exclude any word that is a substring of another word in the set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just collect the words that aren't in any different word?

```
res = [word
       for word in l1
       if not any(word in other != word
                  for other in l1)]
```

Comment: Note that this solution will leave duplicates, if there are any.

Answer (score 2):

Since I assume you'd want to get rid of duplicates as well, this should do:

```
str1 = "dogwood;dog;cat;cattree;cattree;"

words = str1.split(';')
result = ';'.join({w for w in words if not any(w in o and o != w for o in words)})
print(result)
```

Result:

```
dogwood;cattree
```

Comment: Although `word in other != word` and `word in other and other != word` evaluate to the same result, I don't think the first one is faster and it's certainly not as readable - so I favour the second. As for the `set()`, I agree, `{}` is as readable and cleaner - changing that.

Answer (score -2):

When you convert a string to a set, the string is treated as a sequence of characters, so you get a set of all the characters, not a set containing the string.

Just convert the list of strings that you get from `split()` into a set.

Then use `";".join()` to combine them back into a string.

```
res = ";".join(set(str1[:-1].split(";")))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but how to get the result: "dogwood;cattree"?

Comment: Join the set back together with `";".join()`